# How to change shell in unix

Tags: unix, ssh

I'm new to unix. I need to copy file over ssh. This is what I do

```
me@localhost ~ $ ssh you@remotehost
```

Then I established ssh so I get

```
you@remotehost ~ $
```

I'd like to use scp to copy files from localhost to remotehost. Once I have ssh connection, how do I change to prompt back to me@localhost so that I can use the scp command? Is there a command for that?

Edit: The reason I need the ssh is because after I copied the file I have to execute it. Is there a way to remain in the ssh session and use scp to copy the file that I'm editing at localhost

Comment: Yes, look at my answer. You will need to know the hostname or IP of your localhost. If you are behind a router (like with the case of cable internet) you will need to set up port forwarding on your router. Or you could just open up a second terminal. Use one to ssh in, and the other to scp the file over. Are you trying to script this?

Comment: yeah, that'd work, but I'm unfortunately behind a firewall. Opening another terminal window seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most shells exit with `exit`. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> may also work.

Comment: You could open another terminal window or console instead.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to first create an SSH connection to use SCP. Simply use the scp command from your shell, and it will connect to the other server.

Answer (score 0):

You can also:

```
scp /path/to/local-file you@remotehost:/remote/path
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `screen` command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scp on either side. Here are two examples:

If you are on your local host:

`scp myfile you@remotehost:`

If you are on the remote host:

`scp you@<localhost's hostname>:myfile .`

Substitute your localhost's hostname for `<localhost's hostname>` in the second command. If you are behind a router, it will be easier to use the first one.

Both assume that myfile is in the home directory on localhost and is being sent to the home directory on remotehost.